# Easiest way to create a Custom control with inner html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-controls

I have an *.aspx Page with several controls, and one of them is a Lightbox. The code of the lightbox is the following one:

```
public partial class Lightbox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string CloseLink { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
    public bool ShowModalRedirect { get; set; }
    public string ModalName { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<div id='<%=ModalName%>' class="modal hide fade <%= CssClass %>">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="closePopup" CssClass="close" runat="server" >&times;</asp:HyperLink>
        <h3>
            <asp:Literal ID="header" Text='<%# Header %>' runat="server" />
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:Literal ID="body" Text='<%# Body %>'  runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
    <%
    if (ShowModalRedirect) {
        %>
        <a href="<%= CloseLink %>" id="my-modal-redirect" class="link-fade-invisible" style="display: none;"></a>
    <% } %>
```

And, for the time being, it is used in the following way in a page called main.aspx:

```
<block:Lightbox ID="productsLightbox" CloseLink="<%# ProductsUri %>" ModalName="mymodal-discounts" CssClass="modal-discounts" ShowModalRedirect="true" runat="server" ></block:Lightbox>
```

The Header and Body properties of the Lightbox, which can be HTML strings, are filled in code-behind of main.aspx. I would wish to free the code behind from that responsibility and be able to do the following:

```
<block:Lightbox ID="productsLightbox" CloseLink="<%# ProductsUri %>" ModalName="mymodal-discounts" CssClass="modal-discounts" ShowModalRedirect="true" runat="server" >
    <div>Any HTML here</div>
</block:Lightbox>
```

I'd wish the inner HTML to become the Body of my control. How can I do that? Is there any way to do the same for both the header and the body at the same time?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand what you are asking then a Templated Control may be the way to go.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36574bf6(v=vs.100).aspx